# Dataframe .join creates NaN valued column from actual values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, countvectorizer

What I want to do is create a bag of words for 11410 strings and then append at the end of the word columns the result that I have stored in another dataframe. I have a dataframe with the column 'result' which I am trying to append as a new column next to my existing bag-of-words dataframe. However, I get a column that is full of 'NaN' values.

My dataframe is 11410 x 111 in dimension, and I want to add my dataframe column as the new column at the end. My code is as follows

```
bow = vectorizer.fit_transform(df_train['text']) #creates the vectorizer with the bag of words

bow_df = pd.DataFrame(bow.toarray(),columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()) # turn the result to a dataframe

res = df_train['result']      #column of the dataframe that I want to insert

bow_df = bow_df.join(res)     #this SHOULD (? but doesn't) do what I want
```

Therefore I end up with a 11410 x 112 but the last column is full of NaN's.

My res structure:

```
226115    POS
191228    NEU
198033    NEG
100300    NEU
208472    POS
         ... 
119879    POS
103694    NEU
131932    NEU
146867    NEU
121958    NEU
```

My bow_df structure:

```
 age ages also amp apollo approval approved arm astrazeneca aug  ...  \
0       0    0    0   0      0        0        0   0           0   0  ...   
1       0    0    0   0      0        0        0   0           0   0  ...   
2       0    0    0   0      0        0        0   0           0   0  ...   
3       0    0    0   0      0        0        0   0           0   0  ...   
4       0    0    0   0      0        0        1   0           0   0  ...   
...    ..  ...  ...  ..    ...      ...      ...  ..         ...  ..  ...   
11405   0    0    0   0      0        1        0   0           0   0  ...   
11406   0    0    0   0      0        0        0   0           0   0  ...   
11407   0    0    0   0      0        0        0   0           0   0  ...   
11408   1    0    0   0      0        0        0   0           0   1  ...   
11409   1    0    0   0      0        0        0   0           0   0  ...   

      urban us use vaccinated vaccination vaccine vaccines world would year  
0         0  0   0          0           0       0        0     0     0    0  
1         0  0   0          0           0       0        0     0     0    0  
2         0  0   0          0           0       0        0     0     0    0  
3         0  0   0          0           0       0        1     0     0    0  
4         0  0   0          0           0       1        0     0     0    0  
...     ... ..  ..        ...         ...     ...      ...   ...   ...  ...  
11405     0  0   1          0           0       0        0     0     0    0  
11406     0  0   0          0           0       0        0     0     0    0  
11407     0  0   0          0           0       0        0     0     0    0  
11408     0  0   0          0           0       0        0     0     0    0  
11409     0  0   0          0           0       0        0     0     0    0
```

I even tried to `bow_df = bow_df.astype(str)` in case it was the type but didn't work.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a quick look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Without knowing how `bow`, `bow_df` and `res` looks like (provide the data or at least a minimal reproducable example) it is hard to help

Comment: I just send you a link....quote from there: "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?"

Comment: have you tried `bow_df['result'] = res`

Comment: @ZLi yes but still NaN, i am sure its a type incompatibility since res has the correct values but doesnt assign them properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because the index are not matched. Try `bow_df['result'] = res.values` to remove the RHS index.

Answer (score 0):

[join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html?highlight=join#pandas.DataFrame.join) will join index-on-index if not otherwise specified (kwarg `on`). `res` has indexes that are not in `range(11410)`, so you'll have to reset the index before joining:

```
res.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

or building from `df_train`:

```
res = df_train['result'].reset_index(drop=True)
```